# org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate QueryTranslatorFactory: org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTransactionFactory

Tags: hibernate

why this exception is occure when i run query from hql editor

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate QueryTranslatorFactory: org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTransactionFactory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createQueryTranslatorFactory(SettingsFactory.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:264)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createQueryTranslatorFactory(SettingsFactory.java:388)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTransactionFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:262)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 24):

I had the same exception when moved from hibernate 3 to hibernate 4 but when I tried to change the

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

with

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

it worked for me.
I hope that help you.

Answer (score 3):

There is minor change in new APIS.
pls replace property value with

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory.
```

NOTE: there is new package called '**internal**' hierarchy introduced.

Answer (score 0):

The correct name of classic query translator factory is `org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTransactorFactory`, use it in properties instead of the incorrect one (`org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTransactionFactory`).

Answer (score 0):

The correct name is

```
org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslactorFactory
```

Pls note that **'l'** is missing in the previous comment.

Comment: Translactor? Never heard of that word before. Do you mean "Translator"?