# could not instantiate QueryTranslatorFactory: org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory

Tags: java, swing, hibernate, netbeans

(Preface: this is not a duplicate of "[org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate QueryTranslatorFactory: org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTransactionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582478/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-could-not-instantiate-querytranslatorfactory)" because the answer to that involved adding **internal** to the package, which mine does).

I am following the Netbeans tutorial ["Using Hibernate in a Java Swing Application"](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html)

And I am at the line [Creating Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs From a Database](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html#05b)

When I use the "Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs from Database" wizard, I get the following dialog:

[image]

Because the message in red is cut off, I copy/pasted it here:

```
Hibernate configuration fails with message:
could not instantiate QueryTranslatorFactory: org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
see message.log for exception details.
```

My questions:

1. Does anyone know what may cause this? I double-checked my dependencies and my .xml file. Obviously, I'm brand new to Hibernate so I have no idea what else to try.
2. It says to check "message.log". Where might this be located? Is there a default location for this?

UPDATE:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a strange twist of fate, I got it to work by **removing** the word "internal" from the `factory_class` classpath.

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

I won't say that is an **answer**, though, because I am really confused as to why this is. Everything I've read says that

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

...is for **Hibernate 3**

Whereas:

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

... is for **Hibernate 4**.

And I'm certain my platform is Hibernate 4:

[image]

So, I'm still really confused as to what's going on....