# SAXParseException; The content of element type "session-factory" must match "(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)"

Tags: java, hibernate

I know this question is asked like a million times, I read them all but could not find a solution.

I'm new to Hibernate and I'm trying to get some values from a database and show it in a JSP that is controlled by a servlet. But every time I run my project i get this error:

[image: ExceptionInInitializerError]

When I go and see the logs I see this:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[be.coeneivan.servlet.AdminPane]: 

Servlet.service() for servlet be.coeneivan.servlet.AdminPane threw exception
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at be.coeneivan.DB.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:30)
    at be.coeneivan.DB.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:20)
    at be.coeneivan.DB.KokenHelper.<init>(KokenHelper.java:17)
    at be.coeneivan.servlet.AdminPane.doGet(AdminPane.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2075)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2054)
    at be.coeneivan.DB.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:25)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 21; The content of element type "session-factory" must match "(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1994)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:879)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2155)
    ... 36 more
```

And I really don't know why it happens. The error comes from the HibernateUtil class so here is that class:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
public class HibernateUtil {


        private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

        private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
            try {
                // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
                return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            }
            catch (Throwable ex) {
                // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }

    }
```

Nothing special, just the default HibernateUtil class...
The servlet that calls this class is:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
public class KokenHelper {
    Session session = null;

    public KokenHelper() {
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   }

    public List<Koken> getKokenList() {
        List<Koken> kokenList = null;
        try {
            kokenList = session.createQuery("FROM koken").list();
            for (Koken kok : kokenList){
                System.out.println(kok.getType());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return kokenList;
    }
}
```

I tried every thing that I saw in other post, I don't know if any of you could help me. But if you can, THANK YOU!

> Update here is my XML

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.177:3307/webjava?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">usbw</property>
    <mapping resource="be/coeneivan/DB/Koken.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="be/coeneivan/DB/User.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="be/coeneivan/DB/Userkoken.hbm.xml"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Look at the exception - the problem is with your XML: Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 21; The content of element type "session-factory" must match "(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)". You haven't shown us your XML, but it looks like the problem is on line 16...

Comment: As an additional info: The `session-factory` element is part of the `hibernate.cfg.xml` configuration file. This file is obviously invalid.

Comment: I just edited my post to show you the xml file. I haven't change anything there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8961713/2349421
simply replace

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

with

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your "hibernate.cfg.xml" configuration file is simply invalid. The error message already told you that

> The content of element type "session-factory" must match "(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)".

Your config file shows first some properties, then some mappins, then again sme properties. This is invalid because you must obey the given order of the DTD. So the correct file should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.177:3307/webjava?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">usbw</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
        <mapping resource="be/coeneivan/DB/Koken.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="be/coeneivan/DB/User.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="be/coeneivan/DB/Userkoken.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Well ... then this is another question.

Comment: Indeed, but I already found the answer. Thank you very much for your help!